# Print Hexadecimal with padded zeroes in C

Tags: c, hex

I have `%#x` to print the hexadecimal representation of a number. For 5, it is printing `0x5` but I want it to print `0x00000005` with 8 zeros padded. I tried `%#08x` but this seems to remove `0x` from the output which I want to keep. Then I tried `%#080x` which padded the the output with lots of zeros. How can I fix this so that I get to keep `0x`?

Comment: `"%#08x"` should do it, else try `"0x%08x"`.

Comment: [Proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96847ec3c9563653).

Comment: On review, the `8` is the width of the output implies "%#010x" may be needed to get the 2 char "0x" and then 8 char "00000005".  IAC, I suspect you have a non-compliant compiler.

Comment: @chux `0x%08x` worked!

Comment: Note: I prefer "0x%08X" over "0x%08x" and also over using the "#".  Your result may vary.  Sure someone else will post a nice complete answer concerning the whys.

Comment: read about the format strings [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: How are you printing the the value where?